# Design Approach of a New ERP (3-tier) - Please advice

Tags: architecture, 3-tier, erp

I am currently designing a new ERP which will have 10 different modules.

I am using SQL server for database. .NET platform for programming.

For desktop part, I am using WPF, for Web, ASP.NET

I am interested in knowing your opinion about the architecture of the software. Also should I use Entity Framework and WCF?

I have previously written ERP but with a 2-tier approach. This will be my first time to try new platform and concepts.

I currently have a set of libraries which I use to handle data operations from/to a data entry window (a form or a web page) using a class (as a wrapper to table) and to database.

I would be happy to hear the suggestions.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Anybody has to say something on this?

Comment: I think your question is too general- without describing the particulars of your application, we can only suggest very general things, such as "you can create a WCF / Web service that will serve both your web and desktop client", or "you're probably better off using nHibernate than EF".

Answer (score 0):

i would like to sugest you 2 things:

1. Create Database Abstration, so you can connect to SQL server or
   Oracle database.
2. Make sure the interface look the same
3. Centralize your database.

...

regards